# How to tell JUnit to ignore nested exceptions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit4

If I have 2 classes as such:

```
public class A {

    public A(boolean bool){
        if(bool){
            // currently broken
            // would throw RuntimeException
        }
        B.doSomething();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class B {

    public static void doSomething() throws RuntimeException{
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

and my unit test for class `A` would be along the lines of:

```
public class ATest {
    @Test (expected=RuntimeException)
    public void testA(){
        new A(true);
    }
}
```

As it is, the test would succeed due to class `B` method also throwing a `RuntimeException` and the fact that `A` is broken would not be immediately visible.

Is it possible to tell JUnit to somehow ignore the exceptions coming from `B` without the use of mocking frameworks?

Comment: short answer : no. Explanation: Only A should be the unit-under-test. B is a dependency

Comment: My guess: using a try catch block within your test could help you, but it kind of ruins the test (imho).

Comment: Make tests that test `A` and `B` separately.

Answer (score 1):

No - the result of calling the method is a `RuntimeException`, and that's what you're testing.  How is JUnit meant to tell the difference between a `RuntimeException` from the exact method you're calling, and one from a dependent call? One of the rules of testing is that you're not meant to care about the details of *how* the result is obtained, just that it *is* obtained. (For example, you might move the code within the block in the `A` constructor into a separate method, and that shouldn't break the test.)

At the moment, you should be able to easily have a failing test just by checking that calling `new A(false)` *doesn't* throw an exception. Currently that test will fail, because you're still calling `B.doSomething()`, which will still throw.

Note that most mocking frameworks won't help with this either, as you're using a static method - you should at least consider making B an injected dependency (possibly with an interface) so allow for more control.

Answer (score 0):

You should typically stay away from 'raw' exception classes anyway, so the correct way to solve this would be to create a subclass of `RuntimeException` that reflects what has actually gone wrong.

That way you could refer to the correct subclass of `RuntimeException` in your test case and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a specific `RuntimeException` to catch (subclass of `RuntimeException`) then the only way I see is to put a `try catch` in your `testA` method and in the `catch`, verify if the exception does not contain a nested exception then rethrow the exception or call `Assert.fail()`